# In the R console, how do I delete one previous line?

Tags: r

I know how to delete everything in the console: `cat('\014')`

But there is a progress bar in 'R'. Somehow, it is possible to delete only one line, and not everything at all?

Comment: You can print a backspace, and it will delete a character on the same line. Printing a RET character `"\r"` (in some front ends) will take you to the start of line to overwrite it.  As far as I know you can't go back to a previous line.

Comment: You really can't delete any previous lines ever.  You can get them off your screen by "clearing" the screen but that isn't really clearing a screen.  You can remove characters from a *current* line - but not a previous line.  Once you line feed you can't really do much as it currently goes.

Comment: I am tempted to close as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619560/is-it-possible-to-write-on-a-previous-line but I'm not really sure if any progress has been made in the past 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

Example using backspace:

```
showMe <- function() {
   txt <- '   Hello Wonderful World!   '
   n <- nchar(txt)

   for ( i in 1:100 ) {
      cat(txt)
      flush.console()
      Sys.sleep(0.15)
      for ( j in 1:n ) { cat('\b') }
      aChr <- substr(txt, 1, 1)
      txt <- paste0( substr(txt, 2, n), aChr )
   }
   cat(' Goodbye Cruel World! \n' )
}
showMe()
```